# Data on window from table excel python

Tags: python, excel, row, cell

I have an excel file with certain data on columns A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I. From B8 to B38 there are certain data, from B40 to A80 there are other data. I would like to be able to select option 1 and then only extrapolate the data concerning sect. A8-A38 or by viewing option 2 the data A39-A80. If then, once you filter the results e.g. to the box opz.2 A39 I must write in the appropriate windows the real data to the corresponding line.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

win=Tk()

PROGRAMMATORE=StringVar()
CLIENTE=StringVar()
COMMESSA=StringVar()
DISEGNO=StringVar()
MACCHINA=StringVar()
INIZIO=StringVar()
FINE=StringVar()

var=IntVar()
wb = load_workbook(filename=r"C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\Prove carico\Carico_Ufficio_Tecnico.xlsm")
ws = wb["Carico"]

colgar_range=ws['B8':'B38']
innse1_range=ws['B40':'B80']

elements = []

if var.get() ==1:
    for cell in  colgar_range:
        for x in cell:
            y = x.value
        elements.append(y)
    print(y)

elif var.get() ==2:
    for cell in  innse1_range:
        for x in cell:
            y = x.value
        elements.append(y)
    print(y)

def lookupdata(event):
     print(combodata.get())

def lookupvillage():
    value = combodata.get()
    for i in range(2, 100):
        if value == ws.cell(i, 2).value:
            PROGRAMMATORE.set(ws.cell(i,3).value)
            CLIENTE.set(ws.cell(i,5).value)
            COMMESSA.set(ws.cell(i,6).value)
            DISEGNO.set(ws.cell(i,7).value)
            MACCHINA.set(ws.cell(i,1).value)
            INIZIO.set(ws.cell(i,10).value)
            FINE.set(ws.cell(i,11).value)
            return
    #couldn't find a matching value. Maybe the blank item is still selected?
    PROGRAMMATORE.set("unknown")
    CLIENTE.set("unknown")
    COMMESSA.set("unknown")
    DISEGNO.set("unknown")
    MACCHINA.set("unknown")
    INIZIO.set("unknown")
    FINE.set("unknown")
              
Label(win, text="Seleziona pezzo").grid(row=1, column=1, padx=0, pady=10)
combodata=ttk.Combobox(win, width=20)
combodata['values']=elements
combodata.grid(row=1, column=2,padx=10, pady=10)
combodata.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lookupdata)
    
lbl3=Label(win, text="Programmatore", fg="black", font=("times new roman",10,"bold")).grid(row=5, column=1, padx=20, pady=5, sticky='w')
ent3=Entry(win, textvariable=PROGRAMMATORE, width=20, state='readonly')
ent3.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=20, pady=5)

lbl4=Label(win, text="Cliente", fg="black", font=("times new roman",10,"bold")).grid(row=5, column=2, padx=20, pady=5, sticky='w')
ent4=Entry(win, textvariable=CLIENTE, width=20, state='readonly')
ent4.grid(row=6, column=2, padx=20, pady=5)

lbl5=Label(win, text="Commessa", fg="black", font=("times new roman",10,"bold")).grid(row=5, column=3, padx=20, pady=5, sticky='w')
ent5=Entry(win, textvariable=COMMESSA, width=20, state='readonly')
ent5.grid(row=6, column=3, padx=20, pady=5)

lbl6=Label(win, text="Disegno", fg="black", font=("times new roman",10,"bold")).grid(row=5, column=4, padx=20, pady=5, sticky='w')
ent6=Entry(win, textvariable=DISEGNO, width=20, state='readonly')
ent6.grid(row=6, column=4, padx=20, pady=5)

lbl7=Label(win, text="Macchina", fg="black", font=("times new roman",10,"bold")).grid(row=5, column=5, padx=20, pady=5, sticky='w')
ent7=Entry(win, textvariable=MACCHINA, width=20, state='readonly')
ent7.grid(row=6, column=5, padx=20, pady=5)

lbl7=Label(win, text="Inizio", fg="black", font=("times new roman",10,"bold")).grid(row=7, column=1, padx=20, pady=5, sticky='w')
ent7=Entry(win, textvariable=INIZIO, width=20, state='readonly')
ent7.grid(row=8, column=1, padx=20, pady=5)

lbl7=Label(win, text="Fine", fg="black", font=("times new roman",10,"bold")).grid(row=7, column=2, padx=20, pady=5, sticky='w')
ent7=Entry(win, textvariable=FINE, width=20, state='readonly')
ent7.grid(row=8, column=2, padx=20, pady=5)

btn = Button(win, text = 'Carica dati', command=lookupvillage, bd = '5', width=15, height=2)
btn.grid(row=9, column=3, padx=20, pady=10)


R1  =   Radiobutton(win, text="Colgar", variable=var, value=0)
R1.grid(row=15, column=2, padx=20, pady=5)

R2  =   Radiobutton(win, text="Innse1", variable=var, value=1)
R2.grid(row=16, column=2, padx=20, pady=5)

win.mainloop()
```

the possibility to choose which option (see R1 value=0) for data B8-B38 or R2 value=1 (see at the bottom of the program) for data B40-B80

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.